# Android checkCallingOrSelfPermission not returning properly

Tags: android, permissions

I am writing a service which needs to see if its caller holds a particular private permission. I do not want to prevent callers that lack this permission, I only want to know the status so that I can react accordingly. It would seem that the Context method `checkCallingPermission()` is perfect for what I need, returning 0 if the caller has the specified permission and -1 otherwise. I'm finding that -1 is returned in all cases though.

I wrote a test case (using the similar method `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` where I pulled my package's `PackageInfo` from the system, enumerated each of my permissions (only one requested for the package), and display the result of `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()`. Since the permissions I'm checking against in this case are exactly the permissions I hold, I would expect `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` to return 0 (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) only... buy it only returns -1 (PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED).

I've checked this and received the same results on both a 4.0 emulator and a 2.3 device.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong to cause these calls to fail?

My test manifest includes:

```
<permission
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"
    android:name="abcd" />
<uses-permission android:name="abcd" />
```

My test activity code is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.test.check", PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        if ((null == pi.requestedPermissions) ||
            (pi.requestedPermissions.length == 0)) {
            Log.d("CHECK", "Package has NO permissions!");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pi.requestedPermissions.length; ++i) {
            Log.d("CHECK", pi.requestedPermissions[i] + " " + checkCallingOrSelfPermission(pi.requestedPermissions[i]));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("CHECK", "Package name is wrong!");
    }

    finish();
}
```

and my test results are:

```
D/CHECK   ( 3600): abcd -1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not been able to resolve this within the scope of my service needing to check permissions, but I have found a work-around for the service (and a problem in my test case).

My test case failed because the permission I created and checked with, "abcd", was renamed by Android in the <permission> entry, however Android failed to equally rename it in the <uses-permission> entry. It was renamed to have my package name prepended to it (and this renaming does not occur if I provide a name including a period in it, such as "test.abcd").

Though changing the permission name fixed my test case, my actual case within a service was already using a fully qualified permission name and `checkCallingPermission()` continues to fail. I discovered, however, that the PackageManager's `checkPermission()` method does work as expected (at the expense of my needing to retrieve the name of the caller's package).

So to summarize, the following does not work correctly (though I do not know why):

```
boolean permission = (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkCallingPermission(PERMISSION_NAME));
```

while this seems to work correctly:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean permission = (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == pm.checkPermission(PERMISSION_NAME, pm.getNameForUid(getCallingUid())));
```